# Преобразование строки регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Имеется строка char*:

```
"message=sometext <0><0:34><0><0:31><0><1:24> sometext"
```

Как эту строку привести к виду char*:

```
"message=sometext (0-0:34)(0-0:31)(0-1:24) sometext"
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, входной и выходной формат, чтобы мы не угадывали.

Comment: char* -> char*

Comment: Это не формат. Опишите, как имеет право выглядеть входная строка, какие в ней данные, и как эти данные хотелось бы разместить в выходной строке. Например, `sometext` -- это константа или произвольный текст? Если произвольный, имеет ли он право содержать символ `<`? И так далее.

Comment: sometext - произвольный текст в нем может быть что угодно.
<0><0:34><0><0:31><0><1:24> нужно эту часть заменить на (0-0:34)(0-0:31)(0-1:24) ничего больше не затрагивая.

Comment: ага, а может быть в нём (sometext) `<0><0:34>`, например?

Comment: Уточните, что делать из

    <0 xaxa>рррр<2:44>

или

    <0:34><0><1><2:22><3:33><0><1:24>

или

    <<0><><4:77<xaxa>>

Желательно (если сможете) опишите грамматику допустимых выражений (лучше BNF или диаграммы Вирта), если не получится, то побольше примеров "правильных" и "**неправильных**" выражений.

Comment: <0><0:34><0><0:31><0><1:24> - вот конкретный пример, там внутри больше ничего нет. <number><number:number>

По сути мне нужна только <number:number> эта часть остальное удалить и получить (number:number)

Прим:
<0><0:34> -> (0:34)
<0><0:31> -> (0:31)
<0><1:24> -> (1:24)

Мне не столько регулярка нужна, сколько код на с++ делающий нечто подобное, регулярку сам подберу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Kenpachi](/users/2807/kenpachi)](/users/2807/kenpachi), немного вспомнил, потренировался.

Если это оно

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ regex1.c 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
comp = 0 re_nsub = 1 errc = 8 [Success]
> 
<1><0:9>
result = [(1-0:9)]
> 
<1> yye <2><3><4:88> <5><5:6> <7> <8:99>
result = [<1> yye <2>(3-4:88) (5-5:6) <7> <8:99>]
> 
qrwr
result = [qrwr]
> 
message=sometext <0><0:34><0><0:31><0><1:24> sometext
result = [message=sometext (0-0:34)(0-0:31)(0-1:24) sometext]
> 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

То вот код. Правда замену делал неаккуратно

```
<цифра1><цифра2:несколькоЦифр> меняем на (цифра1-цифра2:несколькоЦифр)
```

только для захардкоденного регэкспа. Принцип работы, думаю будет понятен (результат это копия строки). Вообще см. `man 7 regex` и `man 3 regexec`

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <ctype.h>

#include  <regex.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  regex_t reg;

  char str[1000], buf[1000];

  int comp = regcomp (&reg, av[1]? av[1]:
              "(<[0-9]><[0-9]:[0-9]+>)",
              REG_EXTENDED);
  regmatch_t *match = (regmatch_t *)malloc(sizeof(*match)*reg.re_nsub+1);
  int  l = regerror (comp, &reg, buf, 1000);

  printf ("comp = %d re_nsub = %d errc = %d [%s]\n",
      comp,reg.re_nsub, l,buf);

  while (puts("> "), fgets(str,1000,stdin)) {
    str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;
#if DEBUG
    int rc = regexec (&reg, str, reg.re_nsub, match, 0);
    l = regerror (rc, &reg, buf, 1000);
    printf ("rc = %d errc = %d [%s]\n",rc,l,buf);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < reg.re_nsub; i++) {
      printf ("match[%d] rm_so=%d rm_eo=%d\n",
          i, match[i].rm_so, match[i].rm_eo);
      if (match[i].rm_so >= 0) {
        strncpy(buf, str+match[i].rm_so, l=match[i].rm_eo-match[i].rm_so);
        buf[l] = 0;
        printf ("'%s'\n",buf);
      }
    }
#else
    char *p = str, *q = buf;
    *q = 0;
    while (regexec (&reg, p, reg.re_nsub, match, 0) == 0) {
      int so = match[0].rm_so, eo = match[0].rm_eo;

      strncat(q,p,so);
      q += so; *q++ = '('; // replace first '<' to '('
      *q++ = *(p+so+1);    // copy first digit
      *q++ = '-'; *q = 0;  // prepare to copy dig:digits
      strncat(q,p+so+4,l = eo-so-5);
      q += l; *q++ = ')'; *q = 0;
      p += match[0].rm_eo;
#if DEBUG2
      printf ("rest = [%s]\n",p);
      printf ("ebuf = [%s]\n",buf);
#endif
    }
    //    printf ("eol = [%s]\n",p);
    strcat(q,p);

    printf ("result = [%s]\n", buf);
#endif
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Вот обещанный код копирования с заменой для регулярных выражений в Си (С++) (делал в Ubuntu).

```
// regrepl.h avp 2013 C (C++) копия строки с заменой по regexec()
#ifndef _REGREPL_H_
#define _REGREPL_H_

#include  <string.h>
#include  <ctype.h>
#include  <regex.h>

/*
 * regreplace (regex_t *reg, const char *str, void *replexp[], u_int count)
 *              функция возвращает копию строки str с заменой частей,
 *              сопоставившихся с регулярным выражением reg для regexec()
 *              (см. man 3 regexec, man 7 regex)
 *              в соответствии с выражением замены replexp. 
 *              Производится максимум count последовательных замен.
 *
 * replexp      выражение замены представлено в памяти массивом 
 *              типа void *. В нулевом элементе содержится общее количество
 *              элементов, включая нулевой. В остальных либо номер в pmatch[]
 *              из regexec (соответствует номеру скобочного подвыражения в
 *              reg), либо адрес строки символов (строка может быть пустой), 
 *              вставляемой между элементами pmatch[].
 *
 *              Например:
 *              void *repa[2]; repa[0] = (void *)2; repa[1] = (void *)"";
 *                 удалит вхождение reg в str
 *              void *repa[2]; repa[0] = (void *)2; repa[1] = 0;
 *                 сделает копию str, при сопоствлении с reg
 *              void *repa[2]; repa[0] = (void *)2; repa[1] = (void *)"...";
 *                 заменит вхождение reg в str на ...
 *              void *repa[6]; repa[0] = (void *)6; 
 *                 repa[1] = (void *)"("; repa[2] = 0; repa[3] = (void *)":";
 *                 repa[4] = 0; repa[5] = (void *)")";
 *                 удвоит вхождение reg, разделив копии двоеточием и
 *                 поставит скобки в начале и конце
 *              void *repa[6]; repa[0] = (void *)6; 
 *                 repa[1] = (void *)"("; repa[2] = (void *)1;
 *                 repa[3] = (void *)"-"; repa[4] = (void *)2; 
 *                 repa[5] = (void *)")";
 *                 для reg "<([0-9])><([0-9]:[0-9]+)>" из строки
 *                 "abc <1><2:345> zyx" сделает
 *                 "abc (1-2:345) zyx"
 *
 * Для упрощения конструирования выражений замены можно использовать
 * макрос INIT_REPLACE и функцию make_replace. Они принимают строку с
 * выражением замены (replexp) и создают массив void * []. Строки в нем
 * производятся функцией strdup(), в этом случае для освобождения памяти 
 * можно использовать функцию free_replexp(). 
 *
 * INIT_REPLACE macro делает локальную переменную с выражением замены (replexp),
 *              используемую в функции regreplace().
 *              Это выражение должно соответствовать скобочной структуре
 *              regexp, передаваемого в regexec().
 *              Номера элементов массива match в regexec задаются
 *              скобках в выражении замены. Открывающие скобки в нем
 *              надо экранирвать символом `\`. 
 *
 *              Например:
 *              regexp для regexec "<([0-9])><([0-9]:[0-9]+)>"
 *              и replexp "\\((1)-(2))" заменит строку (в копии)
 *              "=<1><2:22>==<3><4:4>" на "=(1-2:22)==(3-4:4)
 *
 * make_replexp создаем массив void * [] в динамической памяти (malloc)
 *              и инициализирует его аналогично INIT_REPLACE
 *
 */

// "граница" между адресами строковых констант и номерами match[] regexec()
#define PATLIM 4096

// делает локальную переменную (name) с replexp 
// и локальную переменную (errname) с количеством ошибок разбора replexp
#define INIT_REPLACE(name,replexp,errname)      \
  void *name[_repasize((replexp))];         \
  int errname = _init_repa(name,(replexp))

// размер массива для replexp
static inline int 
_repasize (const char *replexp)
{
  int i, n = 0, esc = 0;

  for (i = 0; replexp[i]; i++) {
    switch (replexp[i]) {
    case '\\':
      esc ^= 1;
      break;
    case '(':
      if (!esc)
        n++;
    default:
      esc = 0;
    }
  }

  return n*2+2; // перед каждой скобкой м.б. текст + хвост + size in a[0]
}

// заполнение массива replexp, возращает количество ошибок разбора replexp
static inline int 
_init_repa (void *arr[], const char *replexp)
{
  static const char *estr = "\a\bcd\e\fghijklm\nopq\rs\tu\vwxyz";

  int i, j = 0, n = 1, esc = 0, err = 0, c;
  char  tmp[strlen(replexp)+1], *ep;

  tmp[0] = 0;
  for (i = 0; replexp[i]; i++) {
    switch (replexp[i]) {
    case '\\':
      esc ^= 1;
      if (!esc)
    tmp[j++] = '\\';
      break;

    case '(':
      if (!esc) {
        if (j) {
          tmp[j] = 0;
          arr[n++] = strdup(tmp);
        }
        long x = strtol(replexp+i+1,&ep,10);
        if (ep < replexp+j+2 || *ep != ')' || x > PATLIM-1 || x < 0) { // error
          err++;
          x = PATLIM;
        }
        arr[n++] = (void *)x;
        i = ep-replexp;
        tmp[j = 0] = 0;
      } else {
        tmp[j++] = '(';
      }
      esc = 0;
      break;

    default:
      c = (u_char)replexp[i];
      if (esc) {
        int c1 = tolower(c);
        if ('a' <= c1 && c1 <= 'z')
          c = estr[c1-'a'];
      }
      esc = 0;
      tmp[j++] = c;
    }
  }
  tmp[j] = 0;
  arr[n++] = strdup(tmp);

  arr[0] = (void *)(long)n;

  return err; 
}

// делает динамический массив и заполняет его
static void **
make_replexp (const char *rep, int *err)
{
  int sz = _repasize(rep);
  void **repa = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void *)*sz);
  *err = _init_repa(repa,rep);
  return repa;
}

// удаляет части replexp
static void
free_replexp (void *repa[])
{
  int sz, i;

  sz = (long)repa[0];
  for (i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
    long x = (long)repa[i];
    if (x > PATLIM || x < 0)
      free((void *)x);
  }

}

// отладочная печать replexp
static void
prirepa (void *repa[])
{
  int sz, i;

  sz = (long)repa[0];
  for (i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
    long x = (long)repa[i];
    if (x > PATLIM || x < 0)
      puts((char *)x);
    else 
      printf ("%ld %sin %d\n",x,x==PATLIM? "err ":"", i);
  }
  puts("");
}

// копирует n байт с адреса src в динамическую строку dst с позиции lvar
// szvar переменная с текущим размером dst
#define dynstradd(dst,szvar,lvar,src,n)                 \
  ({ char *_src = (char *)(src); int _n = (n), i;           \
    for (i = 0; i < _n; i++) {                      \
      if (lvar >= szvar)                        \
        dst = (char *)realloc(dst, szvar = (lvar+4096));        \
      dst[lvar++] = _src[i];                        \
    }                                   \
    dst[lvar] = 0;  dst+lvar;                       \
  })

// копирует байты до нулевого с адреса src в строку dst с позиции lvar
// szvar переменная с текущим размером dst
#define dynstraddz(dst,szvar,lvar,src)                  \
  ({ char *_src = (char *)(src);                    \
    do {                                \
      if (lvar >= szvar)                        \
        dst = (char *)realloc(dst, szvar = (lvar+4096));        \
    } while (dst[lvar++] = *_src++);                    \
    lvar--;                             \
    dst+lvar;                               \
  })

// делает копию str с заменой найденных reg count частей по replexp
static char *
regreplace (regex_t *reg, const char *str, void *replexp[], u_int count)
{
  regmatch_t match[reg->re_nsub+1];
  int   rsz = 0, l = 0, nrepl = (long)replexp[0];
  char *res = (char *)malloc(rsz = 1024);

  *res = 0;
  while (count-- && regexec(reg, str, reg->re_nsub+1, match, 0) == 0) {
    int so = match[0].rm_so, i;

    dynstradd(res,rsz,l,str,so);   // копируем байты до сопоставления

    for (i = 1; i < nrepl; i++) {
      long x = (long)replexp[i];
      if (x < 0 || x > PATLIM)     // замена константой
        dynstraddz(res,rsz,l,x);
      else if (x < reg->re_nsub+1) // копируем сопоставление в str
        dynstradd(res,rsz,l,
          str+match[x].rm_so, match[x].rm_eo-match[x].rm_so);
    }

    str += match[0].rm_eo;
  }

  dynstraddz(res,rsz,l,str);       // копируем остаток str
  return (char *)realloc(res,l+1);
}

#endif
```

Инклюдите в свою программу и вызываете. При желании (экономия памяти, если используется в нескольких файлах программы) можно вытащить код функций в отдельный файл, а в `regrepl.h` прописать их прототипы.

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Похоже все-таки надо придумывать колесо каждый раз. Как хорошо что я в свое время решил не изучать С.

Comment: Еще немного посмотрел на все это и изобразил **regrepl.h**

    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include  <stdlib.h>
    
    #include "regrepl.h"
    
    int
    main ()
    {
      INIT_REPLACE(repa,"\\((1)-(2))",repa_rc);
      regex_t reg;
      regcomp(&reg,"<([0-9])><([0-9]:[0-9]+)>",REG_EXTENDED);
      char str[1000];
      while (puts(">"), fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin)) {
        char *result = regreplace (&reg, str, repa, 100);
        puts(result);
        free(result);
      }
      exit (puts("Bye") == EOF);
    }

Вполне компактно получилось. Оттестирую и опубликую в ответе.

Comment: Добавил простыню с кодом для regreplace() и проч.

Answer (score 2):

В формате php:

```
preg_replace("/.<(\d+)><(\d+):(\d+)>/", "($1-$2:$3)", $text);
```

если перед первым уголком надо удалить весь текст до пробела, а не один символ, то вместо точки надо написать `[^ ]++`

Comment: @ReinRaus, а Вы PHP с C++ не перепутали?

Comment: @ReinRaus: и да, что получится с `<<0><><4:77<xaxa>>`?

Comment: @avp регулярные выражения универсальны с некоторыми различиями в функционале и синтаксисе в зависимости от конкретного языка.  
@VladD на основе представленных ТС данных выражение будет такое, будет больше данных- будет другое выражение. И ответ на вопрос: такой текст останется неизменным.

Comment: @ReinRaus, в C++ (C) для работы с регулярными выражениями используются функции `regcomp()` и `regexec()`.

При этом готовых функций для замены текста там нет.

Comment: Спасибо, на на php у меня это реализованно, мне именно для с++ нужно, так как я в душе не е..чаю как с этим regex работать, там какой-то *особый* формат регулярок.

Comment: @avp а как же boost ? Хоть я и знаком с с++ поверхностно, но не думаю, что в нем каждый раз надо придумывать колесо.

Comment: @ReinRaus, нельзя объять необъятное. 

Часочек поразвлекался - и прототип готов. 

--

Думаю на поиск как это сделать в boost у меня ушло бы не меньше времени. Притом он где-то работает, а где-то нет, что-то в нем не требует библиотек, а для другого они нужны  и т.д.